# How to write xpath for a span class which is inside another span class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the html code:

```
<span class="nav-menu-single-item">
  <span class="nav-text-element" data-dojo-attach-point="textElement">QJH103L</span>
  <span class="fi fi-nav-right float-right dotted-left-border nav-next-element" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:onNextActionClick" data-dojo-attach-point="nextActionButton"/>
</span>
```

Here,  is the main class and other two are inside it. I have tried `//span[.='QJH103L']` but how to get inside next span class?

Comment: Where is the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `following-sibling`

```
//span[.='QJH103L']/following-sibling::span
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an alternative way of reaching to the next span:

```
//span[text()='QJH103L']/following-sibling::span[1]
```